# How to customize return statement in PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'm writing a stored function called `MAKE_EMAIL` that will accept input arguments for first name and lastname and will return a `varchar2` value containing the email address in the form of first initial of the firstname followed by the full last name followed by `@hpu.edu.`

Ex: Calling select `make_email('Edward','Souza')` from dual would return the single value: `esouza@hpu.edu`

Here is my code:

```
create or replace function MAKE_EMAIL(lastname varchar2(10),firstname varchar(10))
return VARCHAR IS

f_name VARCHAR;
l_name VARCHAR;

BEGIN

RETURN 
END MAKE_EMAIL;
/
```

Could anyone please help me how to achieve the goal? I'm new in PL/SQL.

Comment: Are you just new to PL/SQL? Or new to programming in general? PL/SQL has many built in functions, similarly named to those in other languages even. Look for `substr` and `lower` in the PL/SQL documentation.

Comment: I'm new to PL/SQL and have done  lot of SQL programing. Thanks,I'll check those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
create or replace function MAKE_EMAIL(lastname varchar2(10),firstname varchar2(10))
 return VARCHAR 
IS

      email VARCHAR2;

 BEGIN

 email := substr(lastname ,1,1)|| firstname || '@hpu.edu';
RETURN email;

END;
```

Comment: @René Nyffenegger, Thanks for noticing, i have updated the code.